# How to load the first content of the menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website for a festival. The festival program is divide in three days, so I made 3 button to load the content of each days apart.

> I'd like the first day to display directly when I load the website. How can I do ?
>
> How can I change the button design, so that users could understand that it is loaded ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn a').on('click', function(){
            var btnindex = $(this).index();
            $('.pgf .pgfone').siblings('.pgfone').css({'display':'none'});
            $('.pgf .pgfone').eq(btnindex).css({'display':'block'}); 
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="btn" id="menu">
        <a class="learn-more">JOUR 1</a>
        <a class="learn-more">JOUR 2</a>
        <a class="learn-more">JOUR 3</a>
        </div>
    
    <div class="pgf">
    
            <div class="pgfone" style="display: none;"><?php include('dayone.php'); ?></div>
            <div class="pgfone" style="display: none;"><?php include('daytwo.php'); ?>  </div>
            <div class="pgfone" style="display: none;"><?php include('daythree.php'); ?></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it removing one of your *styles*

```
<div class="pgfone"><?php include('dayone.php'); ?></div>
<div class="pgfone" style="display: none;"><?php include('daytwo.php'); ?></div>
<div class="pgfone" style="display: none;"><?php include('daythree.php'); ?></div>
```

(P.S:) regarding the above my suggestion is to not use inline styles, but rather CSS:

```
/* FIRST REMOVE ANY INLINE STYLES AND DO: */

.pgfone + .pgfone{ display:none; } /* hide all but first one */
```

or using jQuery

```
$(".pgfone").eq(0).show();
```

Here's a demo with the required button styling:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  var $learnBtns = $('.learn-more');
  
  $learnBtns.on('click', function() {
    var btnindex = $(this).index();
    $learnBtns.removeClass("active").eq(btnindex).addClass("active");
    $('.pgfone').hide().eq(btnindex).show();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.pgfone + .pgfone{ display: none; }
.active{background:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn" id="menu">
  <a class="learn-more active">JOUR 1</a>
  <a class="learn-more">JOUR 2</a>
  <a class="learn-more">JOUR 3</a>
</div>

<div class="pgf">
  <div class="pgfone">ONE</div>
  <div class="pgfone">TWO</div>
  <div class="pgfone">THREE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. It work. Any chance you have an idea about how to make the button design selected (like adding a different background color when it is selected ?) Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Simtwo expanded. Basically adding and removing a desired class.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect. Now I'm searching for a way of changing the design of the inactive link, but that's far my initial question ! If you have some links, don't hesitate ! :)

Comment: @Simtwo don't. You don't have to.  Set all the links to a default design. Than play only with the `.active` css styles.

Comment: the thing is if I set a background color on the default link as I want, then the active link design (a different background color) isnt visible.

Comment: @Simtwo it depends how much you know CSS: you need to set your default styles before the `.active` styles here's an example: http://jsbin.com/wuhewag/1/edit?html,css,js,output  Also google for CSS styles specificity.

Comment: Ok I see it's working. Thank to your example, I removed some part of my css link design, now it's working. Thank you very much from Paris !

Answer (score 1):

So I took a look into your website and I think you can do it this way.

Add this CSS rule to your page.

```
a.learn-more.inactive{
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Have you HTML this way, use the **[data](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)** attribute to hold the dates on when this buttons will be active. Initially have all the buttons inactive

```
<div class="btn" id="menu">
    <a class="learn-more inactive" data-Date="3">JOUR 1</a>
    <a class="learn-more inactive" data-Date="4">JOUR 2</a>
    <a class="learn-more inactive" data-Date="5">JOUR 3</a>
</div>
```

Then use Jquery to find the current day, and then toggle the active state of the buttons.

```
 var date = new Date();
 var currentDay = date.getDay(); 

 $('a.learn-more[data-Date="'+currentDay +'"]').removeClass('inactive');
```

---

`This solution is dynamic. In the sense you dont have to change the code on cosecutive days to toggle your buttons. This will automatically calculate which date it is and then activate the button accordingly`. So you can enjoy the festival rather than sitting and tinkering the code :)